# What is an appropriate data structure for polynomial distributed lag models in R?

Tags: r, regression, mathematical-statistics, econometrics

I would like to it a distributed lag model for longitudinal data with three lags:

$$
Y_{it}=\alpha + \sum_{l=0}^{3}\beta_{j}x_{it-3} + \text{other predictors} +\epsilon_{it}
$$

To create the lagged variables,`R`:

```
x <- 1:10
lag <- 3

\embed(c(rep(NA, lag), x), lag)

            X1   X2  X3
          [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]       NA   NA   NA
 [2,]        1   NA   NA
 [3,]        2    1   NA
 [4,]        3    2    1
 [5,]        4    3    2
 [6,]        5    4    3
 [7,]        6    5    4
 [8,]        7    6    5
 [9,]        8    7    6
[10,]        9    8    7
[11,]       10    9    8

\now I may run a regression

lm(Y ~ X + X1+X2+X3)
```

However, such model is going to expirience high degree of multicollinearity. Therefore I would like to use a Polynomial distributed lag:

$$
\beta_{it} = a_{0} + a_{1}i + a_{2}i^2 +\ldots+a_{q}i^q
$$
where $q$ is the degree of the polynomial and $i$ the lag length. Another formulation is
$$
\beta_{i} = a_{0} + \sum_{j=1}^{q}a_{j}f_{j}(i)
$$
Where $f_{j}(i)$ is a polynomial of degree $j$ in the lag length $i$.

I could not find any packages in `R` for panel data and Polynomial distributed lags. Is it safely to assume that the data structure for `q=3`looks like this:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]    1   NA   NA
 [3,]    2    1   NA
 [4,]    3    4    1
 [5,]    4    9    8
 [6,]    5    16    27
 [7,]    6    25    64
 [8,]    7    6    125
 [9,]    8    49    6
[10,]    9    64    343
[11,]   10    9    512
```

Comment: What is exactly the question here? Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822535/fitting-polynomial-model-to-data-in-r